# Sum of all Object Keys returns a String, not a Number as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to add all the values of an object into one variable for the total, but I seem to be concatenating them instead?

```
binance.depth("BNBBTC", (error, depth, symbol) => {
  a = 0;
  for (value in depth.bids){
    a += value;
  };
console.log(a);
});
```

This is the output:

```
00.001081000.001080900.001080800.001080200.001080000.001079700.001079600.001079100
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Not enough information, what is `binance`? my guess is you are concatenating strings and not numbers

Comment: Try converting `value` to a number before adding: `a += Number(value)`

Comment: Sorry, im using binance API

Comment: Can you post the content of `depth.bids`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unexpected behavior of your code is a side effect of adding a `String` and a `Number` together. Unlike other languages that complain about adding a Number to a String or vice versa, JavaScript will implicitly convert a `Number` to a `String` and not complain at all.

This is discussed in Section 2 of the [2ality Blog Post, *JavaScript quirk 1: implicit conversion of values*](http://2ality.com/2013/04/quirk-implicit-conversion.html). See below excerpt:

> #### 2. Implicit conversion of strings
>
> *In web development, you often get values as strings that are actually numbers or booleans. For example, when users enter this kind of data in a form. If you forget to explicitly convert these strings then JavaScript will surprise you negatively in two ways: First, there will be no warning. Second, the values will be converted automatically, but wrongly. The plus operator (+), for instance, is problematic, because it concatenates strings as soon as one of its operands is a string. During the following interaction with JavaScript, the assumption is that we are adding 1 to 5. Instead, we are concatenating the strings '5' and '1'.*
>
> ```
> > var x = '5';  // wrong assumption: x is a number
> > x + 1
> > '51'
> ```

Incorporating the solution of casting `value` to a `Number`, the above code can be rewritten more concisely with the help of ES6. Using [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the sum can be modularized a bit. I've also included [Error-First Callbacks](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/) for Error Handling.

```
const sumArray = values => values.reduce((sum, value) => (sum + Number(value)), 0)

const getDepth = (data, cb) => {      
  binance.depth(data, (err, {bids}) => {
    if (err) {
      return cb(err)
    }

    return cb(null, sumArray(Object.keys(bids)))
  })
}

getDepth('BNBBTC', (err, depth) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    console.log(depth)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys

i needed to convert to value to a number first

```
a += Number(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe converting `value` to int such as

```
var v = parseInt(value);
a += value;
```

Can not post a comment as my reputation is below 50 :(.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting value to a number before adding: a += Number(value)

Answer (score 0):

All need to do is add a + in front of the string

let a = "10"

let b = "20"

let c = +a + +b //c = 30

In your case:

a += +value